# Compare old and new table and show idifference in the flag column

Tags: sql-server, oracle

There are two tables NewEmployee, Oldemployee. They contain the samecolumns(Empid, Name). NewEmployee contains records from oldEmployee as well as others. I need new column 'IsOld' to display 'Y' if NewEmployee contains OldEmployee records or else 'N'. Kindly help me with the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
select N.Empid,
       N.Name,
       case when O.Empid is NULL then 'N' else 'Y' END as IsOld
from NewEmployee N
left outer join Oldemployee O
             on N.Empid = O.Empid
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return `NULL` when there is no match in `Oldemployee` table through which we can set the `IsOld` flag.

`Case` statement alternatives

- For Oracle : **Decode** & **IIF**
- For Sql Server 2012+ : **IIF**